# Cannot connect to postgres replica server after run pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

That's quite weird thing that I encountered recently

##### Environment

Both server: Ubuntu 22.04, postgres 15

#### Primary

Run this command first `sudo -H -u postgres mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive`

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = replica
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_size = 256
wal_log_hints = on
hot_standby = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/%f'
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
host    replication     replicator      secondaryServer         trust
```

I ran `systemctl restart postgresql` to make sure the setting is good, successfully connect from local machine.

#### Secondary server

Run this command first `sudo -H -u postgres mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive`

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
hot_standby = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/%f'
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
```

I ran `systemctl restart postgresql` to make sure the setting is good, successfully connect from local machine.

Then stop the service, using `systemctl stop postgresql`.

Then clear data, using `rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/*` and `rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/15/main/*`

Then run basebackup `pg_basebackup -h <primary-server-ip-address> -D /var/lib/postgresql/15/main -U replicator -W -P -v -R`

The `pg_basebackup` command ran successfully. I enable postgres service, using `sudo systemctl start postgresql`

At this point, the secondary server always return this error, even using psql to test within the machine `psql -h localhost -U postgres`.

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Can somebody shed some light on this ?

##### Update

I just found that when checking by `pg_lsclusters` in secondary server, its status was `down,recovery`. But not sure why is that.

```
Ver Cluster Port Status        Owner    Data directory              Log file
15  main    5432 down,recovery postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log
```

Here's the log

```
2023-07-20 16:55:43.354 GMT [383847] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-07-20 23:55:43.354 +07 [383847] FATAL:  could not open file "/var/lib/postgresql/15/main/PG_VERSION": Permission denied
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2023-07-20 23:56:39.961 +07 [384748] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/15/main" has invalid permissions
2023-07-20 23:56:39.961 +07 [384748] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I tried to set the permissions as loosen as possible. Either `sudo chmod 704 -R /var/lib/postgresql/15/main/` and `sudo chmod u=rwx -R /var/lib/postgresql/15/main/`, but it seems not work.

Comment: Look the PostgreSQL server's log file, which apparently is /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log (on the secondary server)

Comment: @jjanes thanks, I just updated the log above. Seems like something went wrong with permissions. You have any idea?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't run pg_basebackup as the 'postgres' user, so the files are owned by the wrong user. Maybe rerun but with `sudo` to the correct user, or do `chown` now to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried chaging to postgres user by `su - postgres` then run the `pg_basebackup` then log back root user and check for cluster using `pg_lsclusters`. When trying to start the cluster using `pg_ctlcluster 15 main start`, same error happened. that's weird...

Comment: I figured it out... after complete remove the current cluster, using `sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 15 main`, I create brand new one `sudo pg_createcluster --start 15 main`. Modify settings but this time use  postgres user since remove all data from `/var/lib/postgresql/15/main` step. It worked. Thanks mate